# Spring @Transactional prevent opening of Transaction

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

Iam using Spring's `@Transactional` annotation for my DAO classes/methods for DB operations.
`Hibernate` ORM configured with `PostgreSQL`

`SessionFactory` is created with `@Bean` in configuration and retreived using `@Autowired` in DAO classes.

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional(value = "myTransactionManager")
public int getTotalClientsInDatabase() {
    Query countTotalClientsQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .getNamedQuery(DeviceInfo.COUNT_TOTAL_CLIENTS);
    return Integer.parseInt(countTotalClientsQuery.uniqueResult().toString());
}
```

Whenever `getTotalClientsInDatabase` is called, a Transaction is opened always.

I want to prevent opening of a Transaction as it is a `SELECT`(DDL) query.

If `@Transactional` is removed `Exception` is thrown saying `sessionFactory` is not synchronized.

If `readOnly=true` is added [performance is reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797480/why-do-spring-hibernate-read-only-database-transactions-run-slower-than-read-wri).
`@Transactional(value = "myTransactionManager", readOnly=true)`

Is there any way to stop `Session` from opening a `Transaction`??

Answer (score 1):

Good practice would be in your case to mark the transaction with a propagation level of `SUPPORTS`:

> Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none
>   exists.

So if the parent method is not in a transactional context, this method will also not be, but can.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, value = "myTransactionManager")
```