# is hibernate @Transactional(readOnly=true) on read query a bad practice?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I use Spring(Service Layer and Repository) to do CRUD operations on a mysql database.

**MyServiceImpl :**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
 private final MyRepository myrepo;
 ....

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public Optional<myObj> findOne(Long id) {
    return myrepo.findById(id);
 }
}
```

is the using of readonly=true for read operations a bad practice? what about performance?

Comment: Why would it be? It's actually a good practice, as it allows optimisation by the ORM.

Comment: He's probably referring to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797480/why-do-spring-hibernate-read-only-database-transactions-run-slower-than-read-wri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good optimization practice. You can find the examples in the Spring Data documentation. And you won't need to annotate your whole service with @Transactional annotation because "..CRUD methods of the Spring Data JPA repository implementation are already annotated with @Transactional"
[Getting started with Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, since Spring doesn't do persistence itself, so readonly is only a hint to the provider for behaviour(e.g Hibernate)

As per Hibernate's behavior `readonly=true` will set `FlushMode.NEVER` in current session which will prevent committing the transaction.

If you don't explicitly set readOnly to true, you will have read/write transactions.

Now coming Back to your Question

Looking at your `findOne` method. Looks like you are doing a Read call from database.

So its good to mark it as `readonly` to let your Provider know you are reading only.

You can read more in Detail here

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

[Spring @Transactional read-only propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation)